# Count how many times a patient (women and men) got a consult for first time and how many come subsequently

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, having

I have two tables like so:

```
Table Pacient
---------------------
id|    name     |sex|
01|    george   |m  |
02|    laura    |f  |
03|    holly    |f  |
04|    bill     |m  |
05|    gene     |m  |
06|    elizabeth|f  | 
---------------------

Table Consulting
------------------------
id|diagnostic|id_pacient
01| random   |01
02| random   |02
03| random   |04
04| random   |01
05| random   |04
06| random   |03
07| random   |06
08| random   |05
09| random   |03
------------------------
```

And id like to show a table like this:

```
-------------------------
sex|subsequent|first_time
m  |4         | 1
f  |2         | 2
-------------------------
```

So far i have this from my own data:

```
-------------------------
sex|subsequent|first_time
m  |16        | 1(wrong value)
-------------------------
```

I got the above result from this query:

```
select
  p.sex,
  count(c.id_pacient) as subsquent, 
  count(distinct c.pacientes_id) as first_time 
from pacient p 
inner join consulting c on p.id=c.id_pacient 
group by c.id_pacient having subsequent > 1;
```

Comment: All patients have a first visit. Otherwise they wouldn't be patients. Do you mean "only one visit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to calculate the number of times each patient has visited, then use a case to sum the different columns:

```
select
  sex, 
  sum(visits = 1) single_visit, 
  sum(visits > 1) subsequent
from (select p.sex, count(*) as visits
      from pacient p
      join consulting c on p.id=c.id_pacient
      group by c.id_pacient) x
```

In mysql, you can use `sum(condition)` to count how many times it's true, because true is 1 and false is 0.

---

To ensure that both sexes are represented in the output, use a left join to a rows set containing both sex values:

```
select
  s.sex, 
  sum(visits = 1) single_visit, 
  sum(visits > 1) subsequent
from (select 'm' sex union select 'f') s
left join (select p.sex, count(*) as visits
      from pacient p
      join consulting c on p.id=c.id_pacient
      group by c.id_pacient) v
    on v.sex = s.sex
```

Comment: Thank you sir you have approached to the final result i really want, i just edited the above so you can see the result ive got from your query

Comment: @Genesis You are now asking a new question and have edited your question to refer to my answer, which given the sample data you provided would work. Instead, please ask a new question about how to ensure all sexes are present in the output, even if there are no consulting rows for them. I have rolled back your recent edits.

Comment: Im really sorry, the new question is that how can i ensure all genders can be present in the output, i've tried another solution but it didnt work instead grouping them by c.id_pacient i changed it to group by sex and the ouput was almost the same but in this case female was the output instead of male and had 0 in single_visit column wich is right on this, but on subsequent the output was 2 the same as male output, so how can i ensure that the final output correspond to each gender ie: on female had to be 1 and male had to be 1 also on the subsequent column.

Comment: @Genesis Try the extra query at the end of my answer

Comment: i tried that and returned the same table on both querys gender= m, single_visit=24, subsequent=2